# A functional equation from a regional math olympiad (Dhaka regional, 2017)

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

**Question**: For any rational numbers $x$ and $y$, $f(x)$ is a real number and:
$$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y) - f(xy) +1$$
Again, $f(2017) \neq f(2018)$ and:
$$f\left(\frac{2017}{2018}\right) = \frac{a}{b}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are co prime. Find $a-b$.

**Attempts**: I have tried for several days, but I don't have any clue on how to solve it. I tried substitution, and got some useless facts:
$$f(0) = 1$$
$$f(-x^2) = f(x)f(-x)$$
$$f(-1) = 0$$
$$f(2x) = [f(x)]^2 - f(x^2) + 1$$
Can anyone help with this problem please?

Comment: How do you see that $f(-1)=0$?  After all, the constant function $f(x)=1$ satisfies the functional equation (though not the condition that $f(2017)\neq f(2018)$ of course).

Comment: @Alphanerd  Good catch, but that version adds the condition that $f(1)=2$ which makes the problem quite easy.  Was that condition meant to be present here?

Comment: @Alphanerd Thanks a lot. But what do I do with this question now? Am I supposed to delete this?

Comment: Once again:  the older version is quite different from this one unless you intended to add the condition that $f(1)=2$.

Comment: The condition f(1)= 2 was not given in the question

Comment: Then the solution to the earlier post is not (apparently) relevant.  Can you answer my question about $f(-1)$?  Why did you say it was $0$?  That is not implied by the functional equation.  If it is true you must use some additional information.

Comment: @lulu f(-(1²)) = f(1)f(-1), or f(1)=1. But then, f(x+1) = f(x) - f(x) + 1 = 1, or f(2017)=f(2018). Since this is not possible, f(-1) =0. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f(1)=r$. Also, plugging $y=1$ gives $f(x+1)=f(x)\cdot(r-1)+1$, so
$$f(2) = 1-r+r^2\\
f(3) = 2r-2r^2+r^3\\
f(4) = 1-2r + 4r^2 - 3r^3 + r^4$$
Now plug $x=y=2$ and we'll end up with an equation on $r$.
$$2f(4) = f^2(2)+1\\
2(1-2r + 4r^2 - 3r^3 + r^4) = (1-r+r^2)^2+1\\
-2r + 5r^2 - 4r^3 + r^4 =  0\\
r(r-1)^2(r-2)=0
$$
Now,

- $r=0$ gives a pseudo solution $f(2n)=1,\;f(2n+1)=0$ which leads to a contradiction later on;
- $r=1$ gives a possible solution of $f(n)=1$ which is ruled out by the condition $f(2017)\ne f(2018)$;
- $r=2$ seems to be the only possible option, and also the one you know how to deal with.